# Apache doesn't match rewritten URL as regular file

Tags: mod-rewrite, apache2, rewritecond

I've setup a `.htaccess` to redirect requests against the containing directory `/htdocs/foo` to the file `bar.php`.

1st of all: I know how to achieve this in general, but for reasons out of my control the `.htaccess` also wants to check if the URL resolves to a regular file and redirects if not.

Doesn't sound too complicated, but I can't work this out. :[

This is my `.htaccess`:

```
RewriteRule ^$ http://www.example.com/foo/bar.php

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule .* doh.php
```

These rules don't redirect `www.example.com/foo` to `bar.php` but `doh.php` instead.

I checked the `error.log` and for some reason the Rewrite Condition is matched although the file `bar.php` is present.

```
RewriteCond: input='http://www.example.com/foo/bar.php' pattern='!-f' => matched
```

Apparently Apache doesn't consider `bar.php` as regular file if a rewritten URL points to it. `www.example.com/foo/bar.php` works as expected.

Any ideas why?

**Edit #1:**

For clarification, this is the file structure:

```
/ (File system root)
|
+ htdocs (Document root)
  |
  + foo
    |
    + .htaccess
    + bar.php
    + doh.php
```

**Edit #2:**

I'm running Apache 2.4.

**Solution:**

The `RewriteCond` expects `REQUEST_FILENAME` to contain a **local path**. Due the missing `L` flag the `RewriteRule` sets `REQUEST_FILENAME` to a URL which obviously is not a local path, so the test for `!-f` matches.

Ultimately, attaching the `L` flag to the `RewriteRule` produces the desired behavior:

```
RewriteRule ^$ http://www.example.com/foo/bar.php [L]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule .* doh.php
```

After the URL is rewritten to `http://www.example.com/foo/bar.php` a new process loop is initiated, remapping the rewritten URL to the local path `/htdocs/foo/bar.php` which doesn't match the `RewriteCond`'s `!-f` test. And `/htdocs/foo/bar.php` is passed through. :)

Comment: What version of Apache are you using?

Comment: @MrWhite: I'm running Apache 2.4, good sir.

Comment: "After the URL is rewritten to `http://www.example.com/foo/bar.php` a new process loop is initiated, remapping the rewritten URL..." - not exactly. After the URL is "rewritten" to an absolute URL, an _external redirect_ is triggered (not an _internal rewrite_). A 302 response is sent back to the browser and the browser makes an entirely new request to `http://www.example.com/foo/bar.php` - it's at the start of this 2nd (entirely separate) request that Apache maps the requested URL to the filesystem (ie. `/htdocs/foo/bar.php`).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> ```
> RewriteCond: input='/htdocs/foo/bar.php' pattern='!-f' => matched
> ```

Not sure if this has been over-exemplified, but unless there is "something else" going on, this is not as expected, given the above directives.

Since your initial (implied) redirect is missing the `L` flag, processing immediately continues onto the next directive. At this point I would expect to see something like the following in the logs:

```
RewriteCond: input='http://www.example.com/foo/bar.php' pattern='!-f' => matched
```

Immediately after the first `RewriteRule`, the `REQUEST_FILENAME` directive is updated as-is to the output of the last `RewriteRule` ie. `http://www.example.com/foo/bar.php`. It is not remapped to the filesystem at this stage. (Unless you had specified a relative path *substitution*, in which case the directory-prefix would be prepended - which appears to be what you are seeing in the logs - but that does not correspond to the directive in the question.)

So, the above condition is indeed "matched" - the "absolute URL" cannot possibly exist as a file on the filesystem.

You then get a *corrupted* 302 "rewrite" to `doh.php`. The request is *internally rewritten* to `doh.php`, but the HTTP status is set to 302 from the earlier "redirect", but there is no `Location` header, so there is no external redirect. (Although you seem to imply there is a "redirect" to `doh.php`?)

> ```
> RewriteRule ^$ http://www.example.com/foo/bar.php
> ```

In order to trigger an external redirect (given the later rewrite), you need to include the `L` (`last`) flag to stop the current round of processing.

You should also be explicit and include the `R` flag. A 302 redirect is implied here because you have explicitly included a scheme + hostname in the `RewriteRule`.

For example:

```
RewriteRule ^$ http://www.example.com/foo/bar.php [R,L]
```

---

*Aside:*

> These rules don't redirect `www.example.com/foo`

Note that if you request `/foo`, without a trailing slash, and `/foo` is a physical directory then mod_dir will first implicitly 301 redirect to `/foo/` in order to "fix" the URL by appending the trailing slash.

Comment: Thank you for your elaborate answer! You are right about the log entry. The input for the rewrite condition is indeed `http://www.example.com/foo/bar.php`. Do you care to explain why the rewritten URL isn't mapped to the file system? Looks like this is the crucial part I'm missing.

Comment: Ah, now I get it: The `RewriteCond` expects `REQUEST_FILENAME` to contain a **local path**. And due the missing `L` flag the `RewriteRule` sets `REQUEST_FILENAME` to a URL which obviously is not a local path, so the test for `!-f` matches.

Comment: "...why the rewritten URL isn't mapped to the file system?" - The issue here is that you are "rewritting" to an _absolute URL_. AFAIK, this is only mapped to the filesystem at the start of the request. But an absolute URL here results in an external redirect (unless overridden by a later rewrite - as would is happening here) so will not ordinarily result in a second phase of rewriting. A 302 redirect response is sent to the client instead.

Comment: If instead, you had `RewriteRule ^$ bar.php` then it would _rewrite_ the request (no _redirect_) and the following filesystem check would be evaluated correctly. However, including the `L` flag is preferable in both cases.

Comment: "The `RewriteCond` expects `REQUEST_FILENAME` to contain a **local path**" - Strictly speaking it's the `-f` function that requires an absolute filesystem path in order to check the existence of a regular file. This cannot be determined from a URL.